# ServletException while trying to login again after logout in JSF

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

I'm struggling with a problem I have trying to perform a logout from a navbar. Everytime I logout from a Session and try to login again, after performing the login procedure the system just crashes with a ServletException error, with very little feedback.

When you first logout it performs smoothly, it just redirects you to the index and that's it. After you login again and try to perform the logout again, a pop-up window just appears, the one you get when trying to refresh a form filled with data for example.

The following code is in a .xhtml snippet, and it's the `navCommandLink` which is in charge of performing the logout.

```
                <b:navCommandLink iconAwesome="power-off"
                    action="#{navbar.logout()}">
                    <span style="margin-left: 10px;">Logout</span>
                </b:navCommandLink>
```

And the code of the action is the following one.

```
public String logout() {
    Map<String, Object> session = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
    session.remove("LOGGEDIN_USER");

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
            .invalidateSession();
    return "index";
}
```

It should just return to the `index.xhtml` page and that's it.

Comment: i am not sure but i don't think you can perform an action after invalidating the session because the bean will have been destroyed.  try this `public String logout() {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
  externalContext.invalidateSession();
  externalContext.redirect(externalContext.getContextName() + "/index.xhtml");
  return null;
}`

Comment: @MitchBroadhead Thanks for the reply. But using externalContext makes the redirection impossible. If the index is in `myproject/index.xhtml` it just gets me to `myproject/myproject/index.xhtml` and if I just leave "/index.xhtml" inside the method just takes me outside of the projects scope.

Comment: try `@Inject private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest; ... private String baseUrl() {StringBuffer url = httpServletRequest.getRequestURL();String uri = httpServletRequest.getRequestURI();/ String ctx = httpServletRequest.getContextPath(); String base = url.substring(0, url.length() - uri.length() + ctx.length()) + "/";return base; }` then use `externalContext.redirect(baseUrl());`

Comment: and by the way shouldn't it be using ajax? `<b:navCommandLink iconAwesome="power-off" action="#{navbar.logout()}" value="Logout" style="margin-left: 10px;"><f:ajax execute="@this"/></b:navCommandLink>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every question should have a proper answer, so let me repeat the answer given in the comments. The problem is that invalidating the session prevents you from triggering a JSF navigation. So you have to find an alternative, such as navigating via JavaScript or using `externalContext.redirect(externalContext.getContextName() + "/index.xhtml");`. Also read the comments for additional information.